# How can I use pointer in structures?

Tags: c, data-structures

When I learn data structures in C, I got an error but I couldn't solve. How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct n {
    int x;
    n * next;
};
typedef n node;

int main() {
    node * root;
    root = (node * ) malloc (sizeof(node));
    root -> x=10;
    root -> next = (node * ) malloc (sizeof(node));
    root -> next -> x=20;
    root -> next -> next = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
    root -> next -> next -> x=30;
    iter = root;
    printf("%d",iter->x);
    iter = iter -> next;
    printf("%d",iter->x);
    return 0;
}
```

```
5   5   D:\Dev C\Projects\main.c    [Error] unknown type name 'n'
12  7   D:\Dev C\Projects\main.c    [Error] request for member 'x' in something not a structure or union
13  7   D:\Dev C\Projects\main.c    [Error] request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union
17  2   D:\Dev C\Projects\main.c    [Error] 'iter' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

In your code a type named `n` does not exist.
That is why you have the line `typedef n node;` to make a type.
In C, the type of your structure is `struct n` not `n`.

So you need

`typedef struct n node;` to make a new type named `node`.

Within your struct, neither `n` nor `node` exist yet.
So there you need to do

```
struct n * next;
```

The last of your errors (though not explicitly covered by your question) then can be fixed by defining `iter` first.

```
node * root;
node * iter;
```